# unable to launch a phonegap web app on aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Could someone please guide me as to how I can launch my app on the EC2 instance? I have created the instance. I am able to connect using SSH. I have also uploaded my files to the instance. I am using Ubuntu as my OS. I have checked and reset the Security Groups rules to accept all traffic as both inbound and outbound traffic rules for my running instance. I am unable to move to next step where I would ideally be launching my app on the browser. I have also installed Apache server and made sure it is running. Am I missing something? I can see my files in the /var/www/html folder when I navigate through the terminal. How can I launch the index.html through the instance?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apache will be surely running on Port 80. So get the ip address of the instance and use it http:// IP_Address to access index.html file

Comment: Tried it @Hiren. It is opening the Apache2 Default Page instead of the index.html I have written. Do I need to take care of any configurations?

Comment: in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf  , there will be document root node, like this DocumentRoot /var/www/html,, have you placed your files in that folder?

Comment: @Hiren, I am unable to copy all my files. Only inde.html is getting copied. For everything else, I am getting an error message `cp: omitting directory <directoryname>`

Comment: Managed to copy all my files. Still not opening my index.html

Comment: default index.html is replaced with your index.html ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89142/discussion-between-pallavi-prasad-and-hiren).